# If $f''(x) = 0$, then f always has a point of inflection at $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The question is asking if this statement is true or false.

From my understanding, when trying to find points of inflection you are simply looking for when $f''(x) = 0$ and then finding values for $x$. So with that in mind, wouldn't $x$ just always be a point of inflection?

Comment: What about $y = x^4$

Comment: How about $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A point where $f''(x)=0$ is necessary but not sufficient.  You also need to have the graph be both convex and concave near $x$, so that the second derivative actually changes sign at $x$.  For instance, the graph $f(x)=x^4$ has second derivative $f''(x)=12x^2$, but since the second derivative is never negative the graph is always convex and has no inflection point.

Answer (score 1):

For a point $x=a$ to be a point of inflexion, $f''(a)=0$ and $f''(x)$ needs to change sign at $x=a\pm h$. So $f''(x)=(x-a),(x-a)^3, (x-a)^5$are the cases for point of inflexion at $x=a$. But $f''(x)=(x-a)^2, (x-a)^4, (x-a)^6$ are the cases where $f''(a)$ is zero but there is no point of inflexion. For the point of inflexion at $x=a$ we need ty have $$f''(a)=0 ~ and ~ f''(a+h). f''(a-h) <0.$$.